# Making a backup of an SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm working on software that has been developed to support two SQL Server versions. We have one version running on SQL Server 2000 and another on 2005. Both are installed on customer sites (two different customers) and I need to be able to get a backup from both servers to do tests for upgrades. The back-ups will then be used to do a final test before upgrades are sent to both customers. By testing on their actual data, the test result would be the most reliable.

But the problem is that both customers don't give us access to any SQL tools to run on those servers. All I get is an SQL Connection string to use with C# as part of an ASP.NET application. So I need to do something smart through c#/SQL statements through this connection. I also don't have access rights to the file system on the server so I can't even make a backup in some file on the server, then download it. So, other alternatives?

Comment: Ask for more access, then ask again, if they don't provide then deliver a buggy release and tell them why! But seriously, what is the issue with access to the database?

Comment: @Paul's is the answer - explain to the customers that you need a backup and why, trying to work round the customer is just going to cause you pain and suffering in the long term. You don't *personally* need to take the backup and if you have to make the case to get one then make the case.

Comment: @Paul, Unfortunately, I did ask for access already. The reply is "No". They know the code will improve if I get access to backups of the data and it's not even sensitive data, since I can access it through my own web service. But they don't provide me any way to retrieve a backup directly.

Comment: @Murph, the customers are paying quite well but they "share" a single administrator. (One guy who works for both.) And he's the one who blocks this access. And his opinion apparently weights more than mine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SMO or SQL DMO stuff sounds promising.  There is a section on performing a backup programmatically through a connection.  Note the requirements that SMO be isntalled, and I'm sure there will be a dependency on how the SQL Server User's permissions are configured that you use to connect with:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163409.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your customer can do the backup for you?

If you have a requirement to handle it over a remote connection, then your first challenge will be ensuring consistent DB state.  If you're running SQL Enterprise, you can do that by creating a DB snapshot.

You can use Server Management Objects (SMO) to programmatically do anything you can do from SSMS, including making scripts to create the DB objects, running a traditional backup, etc.

If you don't need the DB structure, you could write an SSIS package to scoop up all of the remote data and dump it into a local DB.  That would probably be faster than trying to code it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are sql admin, you have (or may enable) access to xp_cmdshell. So after you take the backup (and store it in sql data directory, to which Sql Server service account must have access), you can invoke xp_cmdshell to do whatever you want with these backup files (again, xp_cmdshell will run under security context of Sql Server engine, so it will have access to the data directory).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm no SQL admin. I do have full rights on the database itself, but not to any other databases and not to the file system of the database server. And I have no physical access to the server. Not even through a remote desktop.

Answer (score 0):

either do what paul says and get them to give you remote access to their network and server, or have them get their people to send you a backup of the database.  i wouldn't waste the time trying to develop a workaround.  talk to your boss about why it's important to get these back ups and see if they can provide some leverage.

Comment: The administrator for both databases isn't very willing to make backups. He also causes plenty of delays whenever I ask for backups and sometimes provides incomplete ones. He's a pain so I want to work around him. I've talked to his bosses several times about this, and maybe they might take some action if I complain long enough but I'm not counting on much of their support.

Comment: yeah.  i think it may be time to get your higher ups to talk to their higher ups.  if they want their product to be stable and up to date they need to be willing to cooperate.  otherwise they're just pi**ing in the wind.